# text will replace the actual text in title bar

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried like this for adding secondary  text  to title bar of windows form

```
                 formMain.ActiveForm.Text = name; 


         <pre>
        +--+---------------------------------------+----------+
        |  | Main window title          [text]       | _ O x  |
        +--+---------------------------------------+----------+
        |                                                     |
```

...

I want to add the text like above mentioned image .but it does not working properly

but my problem is it will replaces the actual text in title bar with above secondary text . I don't want like this , I want to add the text to *formain* title bar on right hand side with out changing the actual text..

can any one help on this........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 formMain.ActiveForm.Text += "   "  + name;
```

may do your task easily

Comment: ok but it will displaying like this "formmaindavid" but i want like this "formmain            David"

Comment: formMain.ActiveForm.Text += " " + name;

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to need to measure the form, and work out how many whitespace characters you need to insert in between the current form text, and the text you need to add to the right hand side.

You would then add your text to the current title.

eg:

```
string rightHandText = "[text]";
string whiteSpace = string.Empty.PadLeft( (your calculation for whitespace), ' ');

formMain.Text += String.Format("{0}{1}", whiteSpace, righHandText);
```

Note the += when setting the form.Text, this adds to the text rather than replacing it.

Comment: thanks... but i dont know how do we calculate the white space

Comment: You would start by checking Form.Width to get the width of the form, then work out how many pixels your ' ' character takes up with your current font (this can change with windows settings unless you disable visual styles) You can get this with a little experimentation. You would then divide the form width by the number of pixels in a white space character, and subtract the length of the right hand string and this should get your roughly there. You obviously need to add a handler to the resize event of the form to recalculate the title when it changes. It depends on how slick you want your app

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
formMain.ActiveForm.Text += "               " + name;
```

But this is dirty and undynamic.

i don't know any way you can set the second text with right alignment.
If you really want so, I think you have to create a custom Window by your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.Text += " text you want to add";
```